# Unity left panel application shortcut problem

Tags: unity, launcher, google-chrome, unity-dash, panel

I'm having some problems with the Google Chrome shortcut in the Unity left panel. I don't know how exactly I should address this issue. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiFvP.png).

Currently I'm launching Chrome from Unity dash search. If I lock the app to launcher, and try to launch the application from there, absolutely nothing happens, when I click on the icon. I tried uninstall, then reinstalling chrome, but it didn't solve the issue.